# How to derive lorentz transformation? for $x$ prime and $t$ prime

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

I have seen a lot of derivations where they pull random equations out of the hat. Please dont do that.

Comment: There is a number of ways to "derive" (in as far as this is meaningful in physics) the Lorentz transformations, however they require a bit more mathematical heavy lifting than the average person is comfortable with. If you are not willing to learn some differential geometry it is likely the "pulling equations out of a hat" approach is as good as it will get.

Answer (score 1):

You can see variety of the derivations here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivations_of_the_Lorentz_transformations